# How to show selected items with animation in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 (version **4.0.3**) with tags and would like to show the selected choices by `fade In` animation in the output field and remove them by a `fade Out` animation.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to modify the code of Select2 library...

Comment: You mean there is not another standard way?

Comment: I'm not sure, but exploring Select2 APIs I haven't found anything to do that...